# How do I replace a ListView item with a RemoteViews?

Tags: android, listview, view

I have a **ListView** with a number items. I want to display a  **RemoteViews** associated with the item when it's clicked. So how do I replace or embed a RemoteViews in a ListView item? This is similar to Twitter's tweet function when you swipe the tweet to the leFt or right to display a list of icon and functions.

Also, some body please tag this post with "RemoteViews". Reputation of 1500 required.

Answer (score 0):

Try using RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory. Supported for API lvl 11+